# Error when extracting hashtags from strings in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract hashtags from strings in R, but can't get around the following error:

(Example set):

I have a data frame 'MyData', with one column containing the text of tweets (named 'tweets'), and one empty column into which I want to place the hashtags contained within each tweet (named 'hashtags').

```
View(MyData)
tweets                            hashtags
hello #test1
hello #test2 goodbye #test3
```

I extract the hashtags as follows:

```
MyData$hashtags <- as.character(str_extract_all(MyData$tweets, "#\\S+))
```

This gives me:

```
View(MyData)
tweets                          hashtags
hello #test1                    #test1
hello #test2 goodbye #test3     c("#test2","#test3")
```

However, I want the display to simply be:

```
View(MyData)
tweets                          hashtags
hello #test1                    #test1
hello #test2 goodbye #test3     #test2, #test3
```

No doubt it's an extremely simple mistake I'm making, but no matter what extraction method I use (I have tried multiple), tweets with multiple hashtags always end up surrounded by c("","",...).

Can anybody recommend a way to extract the hashtags in the format desired, or otherwise alter the output afterwards?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
#sample data
MyData<-read.table(text="tweets
hello #test1
hello #test2 goodbye #test3", comment="", header=T, sep="\t")
```

Now use `paste()` to comma-join your results

```
MyData$hashtags <- sapply(str_extract_all(MyData$tweets, "#\\S+"), paste, collapse=", ")
MyData
#                        tweets       hashtags
# 1                hello #test1         #test1
# 2 hello #test2 goodbye #test3 #test2, #test3
```

This works because str_extract_all returns a list of character vectors. Rather than converting that list with `as.character`, by using `paste(, collapse=)` we can control how those values are collapsed and keep it a nice character vector.